# How to sample from an Iterable of generators in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, generator

Given a `list` of `generator` values :

```
from itertools import repeat

ones_gen = repeat(1)

twos_gen = repeat(2)

threes_gen = repeat(3)

gen_list = [ones_gen, twos_gen, threes_gen]
```

**How do I create another generator that samples from the list to interleave the values from the underlying original generators?**

The new generator should produce `1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3...`.

Note: this is a trivial example that can be replicated by `cycle([1,2,3])`, but just an example.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) with `zip`

```
>>> cc = chain.from_iterable(zip(*gen_list))
>>> next(cc)
1
>>> next(cc)
2
>>> next(cc)
3
>>> next(cc)
1
>>> next(cc)
2
>>> next(cc)
3
```

If the generators aren't infinite, and have different lengths, you may want to use a round robin strategy instead.  There is an example in the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Comment: Take into account that this requires all input generators to have the same length (where length can be infinite).

Answer (score 1):

If your generators are all of the same length (including infinite), you can [chain together](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) the values generated by [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
from itertools import chain

chain.from_iterable(zip(*gen_list))
```

If the lengths may differ and exhausted generators should be discarded, use the [`roundrobin()` example from the `itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
```

Demo of the latter:

```
>>> from itertools import repeat, islice
>>> ones_gen = repeat(1)
>>> twos_gen = repeat(2)
>>> limited_threes_gen = islice(repeat(3), 2)  # just two values
>>> rrgen = roundrobin(ones_gen, twos_gen, limited_threes_gen)
>>> next(rrgen)
1
>>> next(rrgen)
2
>>> next(rrgen)
3
>>> next(rrgen)
1
>>> next(rrgen)
2
>>> next(rrgen)
3
>>> next(rrgen)
1
>>> next(rrgen)
2
>>> next(rrgen)
1
```

The 3s run out but the other two generators keep on going.